# Android put AsyncTask return of ArrayList into Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask that does some stuff, but all it does it `return` some information. I'm trying to figure out how to get it into an Intent. It returns an `ArrayList<>`.

```
new QuizWorker().execute(url);

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TriviaActivity.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(QUESTION_KEY, );
```

If only I could make an ArrayList and set it equal to `new QuizWorker().execute(url);`, but it won't let me do that. (QuizWorker() is the AsyncTask, which returns an ArrayList.)

Comment: wats the type of "url"?? There will be a mismatch between the formal and actual parameters. Check the first generic type of your AsyncTask<>.

Comment: `url` is a string, but that's fine, it all works. I just need to set the `return` of `new QuizWorker().execute(url);` equal to some kind of thing, like an ArrayList, so that I can then access it and properly pass it through Intent.

Answer (score 1):

In your async onPostExecute Method, get the array list and pass it to the activity as:

```
((YourActivity)context).passData(result); // where result is the arraylist
```

in the activity class create the passData method and receive the data, start the intent in that method.
You will have to implement Parcelable on the Object type of the array list to pass it to another activity.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! It helps a good bit. Would I, in my `MainActivity in my onCreate have the method passData(ArrayList<Question> result) { }`? And how would I declare the parameter, because currently it wants to give me an error. Thanks!

Comment: no the method will be outside the onCreate but yes in the same activity, also pass the context that is Activity.this as a parameter to the async task so that you could access it in the async task. The method will be public

Comment: But I think overall, this wouldn't fix my problem, because the AsyncTask runs when the app first starts, but I don't want to start the Intent until the user clicks a button.

Comment: but you could receive the data from the async into your activity, once that is done, in the onclick of the button check if the data obj in the activity is null or not, if not null start the activity

Comment: I made a global ArrayList and said that it equals result, and it let me just use it anytime. So I think that worked for me.